# How to show image in 3D view?

Tags: dart, 3d, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement photo frame in 3D view like below image, but not able to implement like given image.

[image]

CODE:

```
class Photo3DView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          elevation: 15,
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color:Colors.black, width: 10),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3957694.jpg"),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

[result](https://dartpad.dev/?)